# Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' with an index of type 'Any?'

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I'm trying to convert an objective c function to swift which is.

```
   +(NSString *)extractNameWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{

   NSDictionary *assets = dictionary[@"assets"];
   NSDictionary *item = dictionary[@"item"];
   NSArray *facilityAssets = item[@"assets"];
   NSDictionary *facilities = facilityAssets[0];
   NSDictionary *asset = assets[facilities[@"content"]];

   return asset[scs_name] ? : @"";
}
```

To

```
func extractNameWithDictionary(dictionary: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> String {
    guard let assets = dictionary["assets"] as? [AnyHashable : Any],
    let item = dictionary["item"] as? [AnyHashable : Any],
    let facilityAssets = item["assets"] as? [Any],
    let facilities = facilityAssets[0] as? [AnyHashable : Any],
    let asset = assets[facilities["content"]] else { return "" }

    return asset[scs_name] ?? ""
}
```

but in the last constant: let asset = assets[facilities["content"]] I'm getting:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' with an index of type 'Any?'

Any help with this?

Comment: `scs_name` isn't here i suppose it's of type `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func extractNameWithDictionary(dictionary: [String : Any]) -> String {
    guard let assets = dictionary["assets"] as? [String : Any],
          let item = dictionary["item"] as? [String : Any],
          let facilityAssets = item["assets"] as? [Any],
          let facilities = facilityAssets[0] as? [String : Any],
          let asset = assets[facilities["content"] as? String ?? "" ] as? [String:Any] else { return "" }

  return asset[scs_name] as? String ?? ""

}
```

This

```
facilities["content"]
```

returns `Any` that you can't use in dictionary named `assets` as it's key is of type `AnyHashable`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to just continue your system of unloading to include the content step:

```
    ...
    let facilities = facilityAssets[0] as? [AnyHashable : Any],
    let content = facilities["content"] as? String,
    let asset = assets[content] as? [AnyHashable: String]
    else { return "" }
```

You might move on from there to tighten up you types a bit:

```
func extractNameWithDictionary(dictionary: [String : Any]) -> String {
    guard let assets = dictionary["assets"] as? [String : Any],
        let item = dictionary["item"] as? [String : Any],
        let facilityAssets = item["assets"] as? [[String : Any]],
        let content = facilityAssets.first?["content"] as? String,
        let asset = assets[content] as? [String: String],
        let name = asset[scs_name]
        else { return "" }

    return name
}
```

As you work more on this project, however, you'll want to get rid of that `NSDictionary` entirely, and replace it with a proper struct/class that has typed properties rather than having to do all of this `as?` madness. That's only showing up because of the use of a dictionary rather than a struct or class.